# Implementing a Map Using OpenLayers in Django

Tags: javascript, django, gis, openlayers, kml

I am implementing a map application for my new job using Django. What it's supposed to do is, after a user fills out a form, it plots that point on the map. I've read some on-line tutorials, and some of them mentioned KML. I am new to both Javascript and Django.

Here's my question:

What is KML used for in this scenario, is it even necessary?

How do I access the information stored in the database with Javascript?

I think that will at least get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> KML is just "array" of graphic objects (and their attributes) that you
>   want to show on the map. It is very easy to use it because google maps
>   API knows how to parse it.
>
> You don't acces database stored data with javascript. Usually you
>   request it from web server, that communicates with database
>   (javascript send's request to some link and receives response).

Above are just some basics (not django specific) that you have to learn.

Answer (score 1):

look at the geodjango extensions to django - it gives you spatial data classes you can stick in your models. Then you have views that return geoJSON data to open layers...